# фильтр поиска для .net core mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Пишем проект под .net core mvc/ef core. Возникли трудности с пониманием как сделать в контроллере в методе [GET] разбиения на условия для EF CORE, а именно: Если в Get запросе нет параметров, то из таблицы выводит все посты, если есть параметры , то должна срабатывать фильтрация и дополнительные условия WHERE. Как заранее составить linq запрос к базе, где where с заглушками(по умолчанию все), а если параметры с запроса приходят, то запихнуть их значение туда?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-column-sort-links

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть модель и объект фильтра для нее :

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(string Title, int Value)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Title},{Value.ToString()}";
    }
}

public class FilterTest
{
    public int? ValueEqulas { get; set; }
    public string TitleContains { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь в сервисе реализую фильтр (я сделал как расширение для теста, но в реальном проекте просто как метод в сервисе на слое `BLL`). Ниже приведены 2 метода, выполняющие одно и то же двумя способами. Первый более применим к БД (например если вы захоитте в фильтре передавать поле сортировки:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static IList<Test> ReadByFilterByExpression(this List<Test> test, FilterTest filter = null)
    {
        Expression<Func<Test, bool>> expressionWhereTest = (t => true);//по умолчанию все
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "t");
        Expression conditions = null;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (filter.ValueEqulas != null)
            {
                Expression left = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(Test.Value));
                Expression right = Expression.Constant(filter.ValueEqulas, typeof(int));
                var condition = Expression.Equal(left, right);

                if (conditions == null)
                    conditions = condition;
                else
                    conditions = Expression.AndAlso(conditions, condition);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.TitleContains))
            {
                var condition = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Test.Title)), typeof(string).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Contains").FirstOrDefault(), Expression.Constant(filter.TitleContains));

                if (conditions == null)
                    conditions = condition;
                else
                    conditions = Expression.AndAlso(conditions, condition);
            }
        }

        if (conditions != null)
            expressionWhereTest = Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(conditions, parameter);

        return test.Where(expressionWhereTest.Compile()).ToList();
    }

    public static IList<Test> ReadByFilterByLambda(this List<Test> test, FilterTest filter = null)
    {
        if (filter == null) return test;
        return test
            .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.TitleContains) ? t.Title.Contains(filter.TitleContains): true)
            .Where(t => filter.ValueEqulas != null ? t.Value == filter.ValueEqulas : true)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Теперь тест:

```
        List<Test> list = new List<Test>() {
                new Test("1a",1),
                new Test("1b",2),
                new Test("1c",3)
            };
        list.ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine(l));

        var l2 = list.ReadByFilterByLambda(new FilterTest() { ValueEqulas = 3 }).ToList();

        l2.ForEach(l => Console.WriteLine(l));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, выбралась одна запись.

Если фильтр пустой:

`var l2 = list.ReadByFilterByLambda().ToList();`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно выбралось все.

Так же в интернете натыкался и на [другой способ](https://long2know.com/2016/10/building-linq-expressions-part-2/) реализации фильтров